# for loop displays only first item in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

My for loop somehome works only on first item of array but not with rest.

```
var Cat = function ( name, src, id, clicks) {
 var obj = Object.create(Cat.prototype);
 obj.id = id;
 obj.name = name;
 obj.src = src;
 obj.clicks = clicks;
 return obj;
}
var getCatList = function (array) {
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i]);
    return array[i].addCat();
  }
}
var Cats = [new Cat("cat-1", "image.src", "cat_1", 0),new Cat("cat-2", "image.src", "cat_2", 0), new Cat("cat-3", "image.src", "cat_3", 0)] 
getCatList(Cats);
```

Comment: You have a return in your for loop, so it will only run once

Comment: because you write `return` in the for block!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statement in your for block will exit the for iteration after the first one.

```
var getCatList = function (array) {
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]);

    // remove return statement
    // return array[i].addCat();
    array[i].addCat();
  }
}
var Cats = [new Cat("cat-1", "image.src", "cat_1", 0),new Cat("cat-2", "image.src", "cat_2", 0), new Cat("cat-3", "image.src", "cat_3", 0)] 
getCatList(Cats);
```

Answer (score 2):

You return out of the loop after the first iteration:

```
return array[i].addCat();
```

Not sure what you're trying to do - add a cat to a new array and return it?

Comment: Are you OK doing that (creating the new array and appending), or do you need some help?

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` in the `for` loop will exit the function.

You meant to write `array[i].addCat();` as the statement, surely?

Answer (score 0):

If you call `return` within a `for` loop, it will stops the execution and exits the function.

To get an array of Cats out of `getCatList` method you can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

Code:

```js
var Cat = function (name, src, id, clicks) {
      var obj = Object.create(Cat.prototype);
      obj.id = id;
      obj.name = name;
      obj.src = src;
      obj.clicks = clicks;
      return obj;
    },
    getCatList = function (array) {
      return array.map(function (el) {
        return el;
      });
    },
    Cats = [new Cat("cat-1", "image.src", "cat_1", 0), new Cat("cat-2", "image.src", "cat_2", 0), new Cat("cat-3", "image.src", "cat_3", 0)];

console.log(getCatList(Cats));
```

ES6:

```
  let getCatList = array => array.map(el => el);
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter how many  elements the array is holding

doing this

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i]);
    return array[i].addCat();
  }
```

will execute ONLY the first boucle in the loop,